# Python: Can a str called from a list to be use as a variable?

Tags: python

I am new to coding. I am trying to create code that will substitute random words into preset patterns. I am stuck trying to insert a variable to call a list of words from which to grab a random word. Instead, Python pulls a random letter from the variable. I would like Python to call the list of words and pull a random element from the list.

I've tried creating a dict and calling the variable as a value but that produced the same result.  Again, this is all new to me, so sorry if the answer is simple. There is probably a method call I don't know about or I am just on the wrong track here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
GH= ['Filmed','Stonehenge','Summer']
LM= ['apple','cat',"lemon"]
TQ= ['bear','orange','hat']

pats_lst = [["GH","LM","TQ"],["LM","GH","TQ"]]

    # grab a random pattern 

pat = (random.choice(pats_lst))

    # pull random words from lists 

rand_words = [random.choice(item) for item in pat]

    #  *** pulls random letter from str 
    # does not call list 

print(pat)
print(rand_words)

    # returns
    #['LM', 'GH', 'TQ']
    #['M', 'H', 'Q'] ** not ,for ex., ['cat','Summer','orange']
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from the list names

Comment: Hint: you need to start distinguish variable **name** from variable **value**. One may need quoting, while other definitely do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bazingaa told in is comment, you can simply create a list of objects, instead of a list of strings!

```
pats_lst = [[GH, LM, TQ], [LM, GH, TQ]]
```

Lists can be of any kind of objects and they don't even need to be of the same kind of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the values in pats_lst array into quotes, then they will be strings, if you remove the quote marks, from its values, then they will be variables, and you will get the random words.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some code examples showing what you mean? Code is more understandable than words ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

```
pats_lst = [["GH","LM","TQ"],["LM","GH","TQ"]]
```

To:

```
pats_lst = [[GH, LM, TQ], [LM, GH, TQ]]
```

In first part **pats_lst**, you have stored list of **strings** instead of storing value from your variables **GH, LM, TQ**. So remove the quotes from each value of **pats_lst**